# RotateTransform applies after Image has been displayed and this causing blinking

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate, rotatetransform

I have such DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="GreenMarkTemplate">
            <Grid Width="64" Height="64">
                <Image Source="Assets/Marks/mark_green.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="{Binding course}" />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding route_num}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And I need to rotate Image according to "course" property. At first, Image shows with zero angle and in a moment it rotates. This makes Image blinking.

So, is it possible somehow to make Image invisible and show it only after rotation? or rotate image before rendering it?

Comment: Blinking? It shouldn't. Is it really blinking (the image is disappearing the appearing again), or do you just mean that the rotation isn't smooth? In the former case, it may be an issue with the emulator, try deploying on a device. In the latter, use a storyboard to change the angle, it will allow the phone to use hardware acceleration.

Comment: I'm using device for debugging, not emulator. Blinking happens in following sequence: 1. Image is displayed with 0 angle; 2. Image rotates according to binded angle value.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess the binding occurs too late. How is your DataTemplate displayed, in a LongListSelector?

Comment: It is a collection of MapOverlays.

Comment: Another fella just added a decent explanation on differences between `RenderTransform` and `LayoutTransform` over on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124065/wpf-how-to-write-text-in-a-different-direction) you might check out, and in turn try `LayoutTransform` instead.

Comment: I have tried `LayoutTransform` solution. But it seems to work only for desktop framework. Suggested `LayoutTransformer` lacks some desktop specific namespaces. Still looking for a solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue using LayoutTransform port for Windows Phone 8. [github link](https://github.com/igrali/LayoutTransform-WP8)